# Change logo img according to scrolling content background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,
I have a fixed logo img as a png with transparent background and some content scrolling behind it with differently colored divs. Is it possible to change the src attribute of the img tag according to the background-color of the content scrolling behind the img?

Comment: Possible. can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can

```
$( element).scroll(function() {
  if(hexc($(this).css("background-color"))=="#ffffff"){
     $(image).attr('src','new_img_source');
   }
   else if(hexc($(this).css("background-color"))=="#ffff00"){
     $(image).attr('src','new_img_source');
   }
 //and so on
});
```

please note the hexc function is use to convert rgb values(as returned) to hex values .